# How can i change a variable name in a sympy expression

Tags: python, sympy

I am working on a project where I need to change all variables that are named 'a' to a new variable ai, where i is the order of the variable a in the expression. For instance if we use the expression: 1 + x + a + a ** 2, the output should be: 1 + x + a0 + a1 ** 2. Here is a code that I've written to solve this but it doesn't work, the expression remains unchanged.

```
import sympy.parsing.sympy_parser as sp1
import sympy as sp
I=sp1.parse_expr('1 + x + a + a**2', evaluate=False)
a,x=sp.symbols('a x')
def pre(expr):
        i=0
        for arg in sp.postorder_traversal(expr):
                if arg==a:
                        tmp=sp.symbols('a'+str(i))
                        arg=tmp
                        print(arg)
                        i=i+1
                
pre(I)
print(I)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is:

```py
from sympy import Pow, Mul, Symbol, degree

def change_symbol(expr, a):
    """expr: the expression to modify
    a: the symbol to look for and substitute
    """
    # define a wild symbol to look for Symbols, Multiplications and Powers
    # containing the specified symbol
    w = Wild("w", properties=[
        lambda t: isinstance(t, (Pow, Mul, Symbol)) and ((a in t.args) or (t == a))
    ])
    # find the terms that satisfy the above criteria
    terms = list(expr.find(w))
    terms.sort(key=lambda t: degree(t), reverse=True)
    # loop over those terms and performs the substitution with new symbols
    name = a.name
    for t in terms:
        o = degree(t)
        s = Symbol(name + "%s" % (o - 1))
        expr = expr.subs(t, s**o)
    return expr
change_symbol(I, a)
# out: a0 + a1**2 + x + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not work because you never changed the expression. When you say `arg = tmp` that assigns a value of `tmp` to `arg` but this does not update `expr`. @Davide_sd shows a way to recreate an expression with pieces that have been modified. You can also let `replace` do the traversal and let it replace `a` as it encounters it.

```
suffix = [0]  #mutable suffix
def na():
    rv = Symbol('a%s'%suffix[0])
    suffix[0]+=1  # modify for next time
    return rv

>>> a,x=var('a x')
>>> (1 + x + 2*a + a**2).replace(lambda x: x==a, lambda x: na())
a0**2 + 2*a1 + x + 1
```

Note that you said "order in expression" and coded as though you meant "order encountered" but in the polynomial sense, "higher order" terms will not necessarily appear later in the ordered terms. Note that `a**2` appears before `2*a` and that is why the `replace` gave it a value of `a0`:

```
>>> (1 + x + 2*a + a**2).args
(1, x, a**2, 2*a)
```